# Turbo Boost cannot start. (Code 10)

Tags: drivers, cpu, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

Turbo Boost driver cannot start in my Dell XPS L501X. I updated the driver, re-installed it and when I open the device manager, it comes up with this error: This device cannot start. (Code 10). BIOS version A08, Intel Core i7  740QM. Is there a way to turn it on from the motherboard or anywhere else? Waiting for your suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Is Turbo Boost enabled in your BIOS?  What method did you use to update the driver?  Did you get it from Dell or Intel?  Exactly which driver did you use?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: This is a photo of my BIOS settings  http://i42.tinypic.com/2utniwl.jpg .. I updated drivers using DriverEasy software. I didn't find the driver on Intel website nor Dell. They only list the turbo boost technology monitor and not the driver itself. Thank you for your reply @techie007

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit @Ramhound Thank you for you reply.

Comment: If you delete the device (and driver) via Device Manager, and then reboot, does it come back?